# Popup box doesn't return a value when click ok

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, popupwindow

Im working with Asp .net MVC3.I'm using text box in viewpage when focusing on a text box popup window will open which contains a textarea and ok button.when click ok populated in viewpage textbox and popup page has to be hided.im using following code,

```
         <input type="text" id ="Comments" class="Comments" value= "value"/>

         <div id="popup">
    <input type="text" id="content" style="width:243px;height:150px" maxlength="250" cols="70" rows="50"></input>
       <input id="popupok" type="Button" value="Ok" />
       <input id="popupclose" type="Button" value="Close"/> 
           </div>
```

and following is the Jquery,

```
      $(function () {
    $('.Comments').focus(function(){
        $('#popup').show("slow");
    });
    $('#popupclose').click(function () {
        $('#popup').hide("slow");
    });
    $('#popupok').click(function () {
        var thought = $("#content").val();
        $(".Comments").Val()=thought;
        $('#popup').hide("slow");        
    });
});
```

Im not getting the Content value on the thought variable when click ok.what is wrong in thie above code.some one please help on this

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('#popupok').click(function () {
    var thought = $("#content").val();
    $(".Comments").val(thought); // val function need an argument to set value
    $('#popup').hide("slow");        
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/8rWSs/)

Comment: NOw i'm getting the value by using the code, $(".Comments").val(this.document.all.content.value)

Comment: but it is updated to all rows.i want this to be updated in selected row alone

Comment: What do you mean by all rows? You must show your full html instead. We can't imagine your html and code, if you are not showing it on SO.